# User input list,then adding the numbers to calculate ISBN check digit

Tags: python, string, input

```
print("""Hi, and welcome to \"GENERATE A CHECK DIGIT \" """)

num1 =input("Enter a 12 digit ISBN number and I will output your check digit:  ")
oddTotal=int(num1[0])+int(num1[2])+int(num1[4])+int(num1[6])+int(num1[8])+int(num1[10])
evenTotal=int(num1[1])+int(num1[3])+int(num1[5])+int(num1[7])+int(num1[9])+int(num1[11])
Total=oddTotal+(evenTotal*3)
checkDigit=10-(Total%10)

print("For the given ISBN: "  + str(num1)+ " The Check digit should be: " + str(checkDigit))
print("Complete ISBN 13 CODE = " +str(num1)+str(checkDigit))
```

My question: I have added "int" before every single list item but found this to be a bit tedious. I tried putting it at the beginning before the main bracket but it didn't work.

Is there a way of improving this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to convert all elements of your string `num1`to integers, and then use list slicing to calculate both sums:

```
num1 = input("Enter a 12 digit ISBN number and I will output your check digit:  ")
nums = [int(num) for num in num1]
oddTotal = sum(nums[::2])
evenTotal= sum(nums[1::2])
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does work. It definitely looks a lot neater. Thank you

Could you share some time and explain exactly what is happening in the following lines 

nums = [int(num) for num in num1]
oddTotal = sum(nums[::2])  (What do the :: signify and the "2")  
evenTotal= sum(nums[1::2]) (Likewise here)

Comment: The second line is a so called list comprehension, which is just a short notation for a `for` loop, see for example [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). For the list slicing syntax(`[::2]` ) good explanations are available at the answers of this question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` with `map` and string slicing:

```
num1 = input("Enter a 12 digit ISBN number and I will output your check digit:  ")
oddTotal = sum(map(int, num1[::2]))
evenTotal = sum(map(int, num1[1::2]))
```

The syntax for string slicing is similar to list slicing, i.e. the format is `start:end:step`.